# Preferred soil for a ficus/rubber tree

Tags: soil, repotting, ficus

What kind of soil is best for a ficus/rubber tree indoor plant?

I recently moved across the US and my very healthy ficus was too tall to bring in the car. My old house had amazing light and the plant thrived but not by anything I did special to it. I trimmed off the top and put it in water and moved it that way; it grew roots and I've put it in potting soil now (basic Miracle Gro potting soil that I used for my outdoor plants, not a specific house plant blend) but it is not doing great. My new house has decent light, I just think I'm going to have to work a bit harder on making it as happy as can be. I think I need to repot it and want to use the best possible soil.

**Do rubber plants need very well draining soil or would they prefer something that retains more water? Is root aeration important?**

Comment: You don't say, but I'm inferring that "your old house had great light" implies that the new one does not, which is probably a bigger deal for the plant than the potting soil it's currently in. By the way, what is that potting soil? You are looking for advice about potting soil "better than it" but don't say what it was.

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question, but you'll probably want to fertilize it periodically for better results. And don't give it basalt rockdust! :)

Comment: Yes - the new house has ok light but not nearly as great as the old one. I think I've got it in the best possible spot. I don't recall exactly but it was in a basic Miracle-Gro potting soil (not specific for house plants). I'll update my question with this info thanks!